# iPhone with personal hotspot not appearing as a network interface (USB) in the Network preference pane on OS X

Tags: iphone, network, usb, tethering

I have an iPhone 4S running iOS 7.0.2 and a MacBook Pro running OS X 10.8.5.

On the iPhone, I have the tethering option enabled (personal hotspot). I wish to connect via USB, and not over wifi, but somehow I don't have the "USB network interface" (or whatever it is called) on my Mac, so I can't activate it... how can I bring it up?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click the plus in the bottom-left corner. When you're iPhone is connected, you should be able to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you need to run iTunes once after activating tethering on the iPhone and plugging it into the Mac before the phone will show up in the network preference pane.

Comment: my iTunes runs all the time. your idea don't work for me :-(